# How can I disable scaling points of canvas elements using fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

By default fabric.js elements come with 8 points to scale any objects. But the app I'm working specifically requires that stretching should not be allowed on a single axis (horizontally or vertically). 
I only want the corner points, not the ones on sides.

Is it that possible with fabric.js?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `object.lockUniScaling = true`. 
Also, you can customize your corners: http://fabricjs.com/customization

Comment: As of v4 it's not working anymore. http://fabricjs.com/v4-breaking-changes

Answer (score 44):

Yes,

you can use `object.setControlsVisibility()`: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setControlsVisibility

```
this.setControlsVisibility({
    mt: false, // middle top disable
    mb: false, // midle bottom
    ml: false, // middle left
    mr: false, // I think you get it
});
```

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Colmea/GjjJ8/1/ (note there is a minor bug with 'mr' control in 1.4.0 version, fixed in 1.4.1).

**Or** you can use `object.setControlVisible()` :

`object. setControlVisible('mt', false); // disable middle top control`

**Note:** This only hides controls and avoid dragging them. But to avoid any scale: use `lockScalingX` and `lockScalingY` properties.

Answer (score 21):

```
   imgInstance.setControlsVisibility({
         mt: false, 
         mb: false, 
         ml: false, 
         mr: false, 
         bl: false,
         br: false, 
         tl: false, 
         tr: false,
         mtr: false, 
    });
```

change "imgInstance" to be your object.

@http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html

Answer (score 7):

Use it:

object.hasControls = object.hasBorders = false;

See http://fabricjs.com/customization

Answer (score 0):

In the last fabric version, it would be

```
object.selectable = false;
```

Answer (score -5):

By default you can't make it. But you can create some functions like : if width = x then height = y with some relation between x and y on some event(like "on:scaling"), you can always make the width and height to be in certain ratio.