# How to enable non-uniform scaling at corners on fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

If you use a middle top, middle left etc control point its possible to scale an object in that axis. But if you use the corners then the object is always scaled uniformly. Is there a way to disable that uniform/proportional scaling on the corner control points?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971363/how-can-i-disable-scaling-points-of-canvas-elements-using-fabric-js) ?

Comment: @Athafoud What do you mean? I'm currently developing a webapp right now and I haven't been able to find any obvious documentation on the different behaviors of the control points.

Comment: The answers on that question (see the link) shows how to disable scaling points and you can change the corners. I am asking if you have tried any of this.

Comment: @Athafoud Oh whoops, I didn't notice the link haha...
Yeah I've seen that before but I'm trying to change the behavior of the actual corner points themselves. Currently the corner points scale the object uniformly and I don't want that, I want it to be able to scale non-uniformly even at the corners.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to set `uniScaleTransform` to `true` on the `fabric.Canvas` instance. It's [absolutely not obvious from the Fabric.js documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#uniScaleTransform) and is only mentioned once in the [Introduction, Part 4](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/) under the **Object transformation** section

> There's a number of other transformation-related properties available in Fabric **since version 1.0**. One of them is "uniScaleTransform". It's `false` by default, and can be used to enable non-uniform scaling of object; in other words, it allows to change object's proportions when dragging by the corners.

You can set the flag during instantiation:

```
var fabric = new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl, {
    // ...
    uniScaleTransform: true
});
```

or change it later:

```
fabric.uniScaleTransform = true;
```

The flag is ignored for objects with `lockUniScaling` [since `fabric.js v1.1.9`](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/576).

The related source code:

```
_onScale: function(e, transform, x, y) {
  // rotate object only if shift key is not pressed
  // and if it is not a group we are transforming
  if ((e.shiftKey || this.uniScaleTransform) && !transform.target.get('lockUniScaling')) {
    transform.currentAction = 'scale';
    this._scaleObject(x, y);
  }
  else {
    // Switch from a normal resize to proportional
    if (!transform.reset && transform.currentAction === 'scale') {
      this._resetCurrentTransform(e, transform.target);
    }

    transform.currentAction = 'scaleEqually';
    this._scaleObject(x, y, 'equally');
  }
},
```

Comment: For Fabric 4 and up you have to use `uniformScaling: false`. http://fabricjs.com/v4-breaking-changes